# ZF2 and PHPCSMD using PSR-2 in NetBeans 7.4

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpcodesniffer

In NetBeans 7.4 I am using a PHP:CS plugin set to use PSR-2 rules for controlling the source code. My colleague has the same settings (we checked it), same version of the plugin, same version of NetBeans. Yet we have different results after the code review.

While this code:

```php
return new JsonModel(array(
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $someData,
));
```

is displaying as completely OK (no error, no warning) after the code is reviewed by PHPCSMD plugin, on colleagues machine this is marked in red as error and it says it brakes PSR-2 rules because the split rows have to start on a new line.

According to the PSR-2 documentation, this exact case is not mentioned anywhere therefore I have no idea whether it is *marked as error on colleagues machine correctly or not* (so it is correctly not marked as error on my machine :-) ).

The question: according to PSR-2, is this one really incorrect:

```php
return new JsonModel(array(
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $someData,
));
```

and should I be only using this:

```php
return new JsonModel(
    array(
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $someData,
    )
);
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid, `PSR2` compliant, constructs. You can test both (bash) statements with `phpcs`:

```
you@server ~ $ phpcs --standard=PSR2 <<EOF
return new JsonModel(array(
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $someData,
));
EOF
```

and:

```
you@server ~ $ phpcs --standard=PSR2 <<EOF
return new JsonModel(
    array(
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $someData,
    )
);
EOF
```

Btw, I've used:

```
PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.5.1 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)
```